# Reading from TextIOWrapper causes UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, encoding, subprocess, stdout, popen

I try to read subprocess line by line:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(self.monitor_logcat_cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)

while proc.poll() is None:
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    print("Process line: " + str(line))
```

It works, yet at some point I get error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-14:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/F1sherKK/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Users/F1sherKK/Dev/Python/AutomationTestSupervisor/session/SessionThreads.py", line 46, in run
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
  File "/Users/F1sherKK/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 89: invalid start byte
```

Is there any way to add/specify encoding for stdout of subprocess? I would like to add error "ignoring".

Is there any other way to fix this?

Comment: So what bytes does the process produce, switching off `universal_newlines`? Do you know what encoding the process produces?

Comment: What exactly does `monitor_logcat_cmd` contain? What command is run in the shell? Are you setting an `LANG` or `LC_CTYPE` environment variables?

Comment: monitor_logcat_cmd is `adb -s 5554 logcat` it is reading log from Android Device in real time. It can consist of various encodings there I guess. For example there can be Emoji in logs. I didn't set any env variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* just set the `errors` keyword argument to `Popen()` to `'ignore'`. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments):

> If *encoding* or *errors* are specified, or *universal_newlines* is true, the file objects *stdin*, *stdout* and *stderr* will be opened in text mode using the *encoding* and *errors* specified in the call or the defaults for `io.TextIOWrapper`.

However, it is clear your process doesn't use UTF-8 to encode its output. You may want to figure out if a) it can be configured to produce a different encoding, or b) what encoding is used and configure that instead (using the `encoding` keyword argument to `Popen()`).

Comment: Thanks. I got temporary solution with `errors="ignore"`. I didn't try this before because PyCharm was giving "Unexpected argument" error when I tried to use that. Yet it works. I think it might be hard to set single encoding for this log. I think it SHOULD be UTF-8 yet there are sometimes single elements which aren't UTF-8. I am not encoding expert but that's how I understand this. In my case I need to save like 20k lines of log from my device, so  if few of them will have "ignored errors" I don't think that will cause me any problems. I fill experiment with various encodings though. Thanks.